# MVVM ViewModel interacting with View, is it true MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm, mvp

Lets say for example we have a single WPF window with 2 tabs and a file menu. The file menu has two items "Hide Tab 1", "Show Tab 1"

The program then has the following classes:
MainView.xaml

MainViewModel.cs

"Hide tab 1" menu command is then bound to HideTab1Command which is contained within MainViewModel.cs

HideTab1 then directly interacts with the View to hide tab1 from within the ViewModel.

Is this technically not MVVM behaviour (more like MVP)? Eg for true MVVM the functionality to perform this behavior should be contained entirely in XAML code or in "code behind" within MainView.xaml.cs ?

I see MVVM applications and examples that do this all the time, however it seems to break the SRP (Single Responsibility Principle).

I see some other applications that do the same with the HideTab1 command simply notifying the view via an interface IMainView which then calls code within MainView.xaml.cs

Whilst I can see that the code is now within the View how is this really any different from the first example? The SRP is still voided with the ViewModel telling the View what to do.

Are either of these examples true MVVM patterns and if not what would be the correct MVVM pattern to achieve hiding/showing "tab 1".

Please forgive any misunderstandings of what MVVM/MVP are, I am doing my best to learn these design patterns correctly.

Example:
ShowTab1 is a command that then directly manipulates the View. I see this in MVVM projects all the time (Lots of DevExpress examples) yet it does not appear to have any of the benefits of MVVM as your ViewModel is directly manipulating your view.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
    ...
        <Button Content="Show hidden panels"   Command="{Binding ShowTab1}"/>
        ...
        <TabGroup>...
    ...
</Window>
```

MainWindowViewMode.cs

```
public class MainViewModel 
{
    IMainView mainView;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ShowTab1 = new ShowTab1Command(this);
        mainView = ... (set this to a reference to the view)
    }

    public ICommand ShowTab1 { get; set; }
}

public class ShowTab1Command: ICommand
{
    private readonly MainViewModel _model;
    public ShowTab1Command(MainViewModel model)
    {
        _model = model;            
    }
    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
         _model.mainView.TabGroup1MakeVisible();
    }
    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

   public interface IMainView{
       public void TabGroup1MakeVisible();
```

A true MVVM would have a ViewModel purely for converting data into the DataContext that the view expects. All view manipulation would be done in the View eg in CodeBehind or XAML. Or is this incorrect?

Comment: it is extremely difficult to follow your question without any actual code. surely you can show a short working sample?

Comment: If I understand correctly that HideTab1 is a ViewModel property (?) then the name itself would not be very MVVMish

Comment: HideTab1 is a command. Eg when you click on hide tab 1 from the file menu the desired behaviour is to hide the tab. This is a simple example, not am actual real world program. I will write something later so you can see what I'm asking in more detail.

Comment: What I want to know, is if a command in the view model is allowed to interact with the view beyond providing data context? In the mvvm diagram it looks as though it is not meant to eg opening closing windows/tabs. If the view model interacts with the view this appears to be mvp with the view model acting more like a presenter.

Comment: I added an example, please undownvote.

Answer (score 5):

> HideTab1 then directly interacts with the View to hide tab1 from
>   within the ViewModel.

This is where the program 'breaks' MVVM. A proper solution would be to have the command change a property on the ViewModel, say: ShowTab1

In the view you would bind the Visibility (using a value converter)  or IsEnabled to this property.

This way the ViewModel doesn't interact with the View directly.

Comment: This is what I've seen lots of, what I struggle with though is ultimately the viewmodel is interacting with the view (via a proxy) which seems to defeat the purpose of mvvm. Why not just use code behind eg a click handler in the view directly.

Comment: @rolls - Because (unit) testing code in a view is really hard. So we try to avoid code in the views.

Comment: Other than unit testing what are the other main reasons for doing it?

Comment: @rolls 1. Changing the view can be done within big changes to the view model. This is because you dont reference controls by name. 2. View code quickly becomes more complex than view model code. The binding, state and animation systems help view models remain simple. 3. MVVM allows you to write application level code without having to consider the behaviour of the view.

Comment: I completely understand reasons to use MVVM, I just mean in the simple case of simple hiding/showing an element (not creating or setting datacontext) why would this not be done in codebehind with everything else utilising the method you suggested?